# plyr for same analysis accross different subsets

Tags: r, dplyr, lapply, plyr, sapply

I'm new to `plyr` and `dplyr` and seriously don't get it. I have managed my way around some functions, but I struggle with really basic stuff such as the following example.

Taking `mtcars`, I have different overlapping subsets, such as `vs = 1` and `am = 1`

I now want to run the same analysis, in this case `median()` for one var over the different subsets, and another analysis, such as `mean()` for another var.
This should give me in the end the same result, such as the following code - just much shorter:

```
data_mt <- mtcars         # has binary dummy vars for grouping
data_vs <- data_mt[ which(data_mt$vs == 1 ), ]
data_am <- data_mt[ which(data_mt$am == 1 ), ]

median(data_mt$mpg)
median(data_vs$mpg)
median(data_am$mpg)

mean(data_mt$cyl)
mean(data_vs$cyl)
mean(data_am$cyl)
```

In my real example, I have an analog to `data_mt`, so if you have a solution starting there, without `data_vs` etc. that would be great.

I'm sure this is very basic, but I can't wrap my head around it - and as I have some 1500 variables that I want to look at, I'd appreciate your help =)

It may well be that my answer is already out there, but with the terminology I know I didn't find it explain for Dummies ;D

---

Edit:

To have a better understanding of what I am doing and what I am looking for, I hereby post my original code (not the `mtcars` example).

I have a dataset `ds` with 402 observations of 553 variables
The dataset comes from a study with human participants, some of which opted in for additional research `mys` or `obs` or both.

```
ds$mys <- 0
ds$mys[ which(ds$staffmystery_p == "Yes" ) ] <- 1

ds$obs <- 0
ds$obs[ which( !is.na(ds$sales_time)) ] <- 1
```

The 553 variables are either integers (e.g. for age or years of experience) or factors (e.g. sex or yes/no answers). I now want to compare some descriptive of the full dataset with the descriptives for the subsets and ideally also do a t-test for difference.
Currently I have just a very long list of code that reads more or less like the following (just much longer). This doesn't include t-tests.

```
describe(ds$age_b)
describe(dm$age_b)
describe(do$age_b)

prop.table(table(ds$sex_b))*100
prop.table(table(dm$sex_b))*100
prop.table(table(do$sex_b))*100
```

`ds`, `dm` and `do` are different datasets, but they are all just based on the above mentioned full dataset `ds` and the subsets `ds$mys` for `dm` and `ds$obs` for `do`

`describe` comes from the `psych` package and just lists descriptive statistics like mean or median etc. I don't need all of the metrics, mostly n, mean, median, sd and iqr.
The formula around 'prop.table' gives me a readout I can just copy into the excel tables I use for the final publications. I don't want automated output because I get asked all the time to add or change this, which is really just easier in excel than with automated output. (unless you know a much superior way ;)

Thank you so much!

Comment: From the code, I understand you want to do the full data mean, median and only a subset of data mean, median.  Is it only specifiec to `vs = 1` and `am = 1` i.e. with `vs` there is also '0' value.  If you want to do this separately, use a `group_by`

Comment: yes, full data and for overlapping subsets. In my specific case I have a dataset with standard variables such as age, sex etc. for the full dataset and then specific variables for subsets (such as eating banana = yes) with additional variables asked only for this subset (such as number of bananas consumed). Now I want to contrast to know the age and sex of banana eaters vs. all.

Comment: when you say overlapping did you meant `mtcars %>% filter(vs ==1, am == 1)` or it is an `|` condition

Comment: I meant that the subsets are not categorical (e.g. mutually exclusive like dead or alive). They are essentially just a list of dummy variables.

Comment: Can you check the solution output below.  I am not sure if that is the expected output but from the values of the subset in your code, it seems to be the one you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option if we want to do this for different columns by group separately

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
map_dfc(c('vs', 'am'), ~ 
   mtcars %>% 
     group_by(across(all_of(.x))) %>%
     summarise(!! str_c("Mean_cyl_", .x)  := mean(cyl), 
       !! str_c("Median_mpg_", .x) := median(mpg), .groups = 'drop'))%>%
   mutate(Mean_cyl_full = mean(mtcars$cyl), Median_mpg_full = median(mtcars$mpg))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 x 8
#     vs Mean_cyl_vs Median_mpg_vs    am Mean_cyl_am Median_mpg_am Mean_cyl_full Median_mpg_full
#  <dbl>       <dbl>         <dbl> <dbl>       <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>           <dbl>
#1     0        7.44          15.6     0        6.95          17.3          6.19            19.2
#2     1        4.57          22.8     1        5.08          22.8          6.19            19.2
```

---

If the package version is old, we can replace the `across` with `group_by_at`

```
map_dfc(c('vs', 'am'), ~ 
   mtcars %>% 
     group_by_at(vars(.x)) %>%
     summarise(!! str_c("Mean_cyl_", .x)  := mean(cyl), 
       !! str_c("Median_mpg_", .x) := median(mpg), .groups = 'drop'))%>%
   mutate(Mean_cyl_full = mean(mtcars$cyl), Median_mpg_full = median(mtcars$mpg))
```

#### Update

Based on the update, we could place the datasets in a `list`, do the transformations at once and `return` a `list` of descriptive statistics and the proportion table

```
out <- map(dplyr::lst(dm, ds, do), ~ {

          dat <- .x %>%
                     mutate(mys = as.integer(staffmystery_p == 'Yes'),
                                         obs = as.integer(!is.na(sales_time)))
                            age_b_desc <- describe(dat$age_b)
                            prop_table_out <- prop.table(table(dat$sex_b))*100
                            
                            return(dplyr::lst(age_b_desc, prop_table_out))
                            
                            
                            }
                                    
                 )
```

Comment: I tried it for both the example as well as my data, but get:

Error in across(all_of(.x)) : could not find function "across"

Comment: @PhilippStaudacher can you show the `packageVersion('dplyr')` It should be version >= 1.0

Comment: I just deleted the package and reinstalled. Still just 0.8.5

Comment: @PhilippStaudacher it may be that your `R` version is old.  I can change the code to make it work with your version

Comment: @PhilippStaudacher can you try the updated code

Comment: Thanks for all of this but since i updated dplyr (or didn't) I'm stuck in a loop of other issues: dplyr requires tidyselect which requires rlang (>= 0.4.6) but I can only get to 0.4.5. 
You mentioned earlier I may have an old R version. It's 3.5.0. I'll see how to update that.

Comment: @PhilippStaudacher The current R version is `4.0.3` and there are lots of improvements, bug fixes with 4.0.  Most of the tidyverse functions are updated, some are deprecated, so it is better to update R

Comment: It kind of works. It just seems to me it's more effort in writing and also - in my case more difficult to decipher. I was somehow expecting this to be easier ^^
Specifically I'd like to drop the naming of variables, and also have the readout not truncated. If possible avoid the line with 'mutate' where I'd have to repeat every input I wrote above for the subset.

Comment: @PhilippStaudacher it can be done.  But, from your code, it seems that you are doing `mean`, `median` on different columns?  Realistically, do you have a group of columns that goes for `mean` and other for `median`?  If that is the case, you can use `mutate(across(yourcols, mean), across(secondsetcols, median))`

Comment: Maybe I should have written that at the beginning ^^ I have a dataset with 402 human participants (each has a unique ID). Some of them agreed to participate in additional research aspects, so that I have three subsets with n=392, n=236 and n=94. But not all of the n=94 are also in the n=236. But all of them are in the n=402 dataset. I now have >500 variables that are either categorical, integer, some even characters.
What I want to do is get for example median(age) for the total dataset, but also each subset. ideally even with a ttest for each group. 
And then repeat this for another 100 var

Comment: @PhilippStaudacher Can you please update your post with more info.  I created this code based on the code block on your post.  If you can show the actual code and what you wanted, it becomes more clear to me. thanks

Comment: done. thanks so much for all the progress so far. and I wish you a great 2021 ;)

Comment: @PhilippStaudacher Thanks.  Have a great 2021 to you as well!  I have a doubt in the edit.  `describe(ds$age_b)` is done after you did some binary transformation for different columns.  I am still trying to understand how that will impact the `describe` on a different column

Comment: @PhilippStaudacher I updated the post based on the new block of edited code in your post

Comment: Thank you so much. this works quite well. I have some questions to better understand:
1) If I already have the datasets ds, dm, do isn't this then redundant with the mutate section defining mys and obs? After all dm and do are just subsets of ds based on the same criteria.
2) Is there a way to output the results for all three datasets by variable (e.g. age_ds, age_dm, age_do), instead of as it is now by dataset (ds_age, ds_sex, etc.)

Comment: 3) can you automate that the name of the variable (age_b or sex_b) is automatically picked as the varname for the list (currently age_b_desc and prop_table_out). There's no need to indicate 'desc' or 'prop table' etc.

Comment: @PhilippStaudacher Regarding your first question, if the 'dm', 'ds', 'do' are subsets, then you can the mutate for mys and obs on the original dataset instead of the subset., 2) Regarding the second question, as we are getting a list output.  The names of the list can be changed as using `imap` instead of `map` i.e. `imap(dplyr::lst(dm, ds, do), ~ ....` and at the end you can use `return(dplyr::lst(str_c("age_b_desc_", .y) := age_b_desc, str_c("prop_table_out_", .y) := prop_table_out))`